# How to display a key from array of hashes in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

We have a table 'Books':

```
id - int
data - text
```

Actually we should have kept data as jsonb column, but we have created this table long back and aren't planning to migrate.

We can cast it to jsonb as and when required.

My question here is

In data I have `{"genres":[{"text":"Crime","id": "1"},{"text":"Romance","id": "5"}],"name":"Harry Potter"}`

I need a select query to display all the text of genres comma separated for every book.

How can I do this?

I tried this,

```
select data::json -> 'genres'  as genres
from books
where data::json -> 'genres'  is not NULL
limit 1;
```

However this displays the id as well and it also displays the square brackets.

Comment: The `data` you have shown is not a valid json, please post the actual json

Comment: Updated the data in the questio

Comment: Do you actually have single quotes around each key/value in your text? Because that would not be valid JSON either.

Comment: I have it as double quotes

Comment: updated in question as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_array_elements`

```
select string_agg(j->>'text',',')  from books
cross join lateral json_array_elements(data::json->'genres') as j
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=14f16f65a145ef07debc329c34cd4162)

If you want for every book, add `group by id` or whatever uniquely identifies a book.

Comment: This query took such a long time. 
I have 60k records in my table and it returned all the records.

So I added 

select string_agg(j->>'text',',')  from books
cross join json_array_elements(data::json->'genres') as j where data::json->'genres' is not NULL limit 1;

But strangely even that took a long time and responded with the whole table.

Comment: what is happening? why am I always getting the entire table?

Comment: @Surya : did you add `group by id`?

Comment: Yes after that I was able to get for just one record. Thanks

Comment: but this results in records that has genres, I need the records that doesn't have genres as well.

Comment: Anyways will figure that out somehow. Thanks

Comment: @Surya : You're welcome. I believe this answers your original question. If you think it helped you you may consider accepting it. If you have further requests, you may ask that as a separate question.